# Chat Server for Android/iPhone/blackberry Devices

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, chat

I want to implement a chat server with many **Android/Blackberry/iPhone** devices connecting to it.
Is there any preferable way to do it. Or can I get any good free/opensource server side solution for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [Scrigno](http://www.scringo.com). It's an SDK (iphone & android) that also includes chat between app users (also the server-side). It doesn't support Blackberry though.